# Quartz Scheduler not working properly in .net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, quartz.net-3.0

[image][image]

I am trying to add a Scheduled Task using Quartz but the task is not getting triggered. I have gone through many blogs but I don't see any visible mistake in my code. Can any one please help me out why Task is not getting triggered.

I am trying this on .Net 6.
Quartz version -- 3.4.0
Quartz.Extensions.Hosting --3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine to me. The CRONjob value 0/1 denotes every 1 second. Is that practical or have you tried modifying to some more delay?

I have gone through a very fine answer recently and based on that review, had created my own version of Quartz implementation on .NET6 over here:
https://github.com/prashantchalise/.NET6Scheduler

I have worked on

1. Segregating configuration including CRON values over appsettings.
2. Dynamic DI and config `ServiceCollectionQuartzConfiguratorExtensions`
3. Configure SQL server and do some CFEF action over Scheduled call.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! 1 second trigger is just to test if things are in right way not a practical one.